# Android - How to stop background image to extend into the titlebar?

Tags: android

Folks,

I just created a new Android application. In the main activity, I specified a background image.

```
<FrameLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/mypic">

</FrameLayout>
```

Within eclipse, in the graphical layout view, this looks fine. I see a title bar at the top and the rest of the screen is occupied by the background image.

However, when I run this on the device, I see that the background image extends all the way into the title bar.

I would like the title bar to stay as is, that is, with the default black background. Is there a setting I can change somewhere?

I suspect it has something to do with the default generated style "FullScreenTheme."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspect seems to be right. Unless you share your styles file and your manisfest, we can't say definitively. Change your style to Theme.Holo.Light or Theme.Light in your styles.xml file  .